# Write GET route in Symfony with FOSRestBundle

Tags: symfony, fosrestbundle

I have function

```
/**
 * My function
 *
 * @FOS\View()
 * @FOS\Get("/myfunction/?param1={p1}&param2={p2}&paramn={pn}")
 *
 * @param integer $param1
 * @param integer $param2
 * @param integer $paramn
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getMyFunction($param1, $param2, $paramn)
{
    return new Response($param1. ' ' . $param1. ' ' . $paramn);
}
```

But when I call http://host/myfunction/?param1=1&param1=2&paramn=3 dosen't work.

What is wrong in definition of function?

---

UPDATE: New function

```
 /**
 * My function
 *
 * @FOS\View()
 * @FOS\Get("/myfunction/")
 *
 * Request $request
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getMyFunction(Request $request)
{
    $requestParams = $request->request->all();

    return new Response($requestParams['param1']);
}
```

And, now I call http://host/myfunctin/?param1=1, but still, dosen't work.

Error: "Notice: Undefined index: param1"

Request for get parameters isn't good?

Thanks!

Comment: With @FOS\Get you can specify only the path. If you need to get parameters on the query string, you can do that with the request object.

Comment: You want use the `query` parameter bag instead of `request`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove the query string parameters from the route.

To get them you have to inject a Request object in the function signature and the use $request->get('parametername') to retrieve then.

Comment: I changed with request, but don't work. I updated the initial post with current version of code.

Comment: Try $request->get('param1')

Comment: Thanks, Carols! Work! Thanks, Federkun for explication about @FOS\Get.